# Are all Artinian Rings Jacobson?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, artinian

An Artinian Ring is one which satisfies the descending chain condition for ideals.

A Jacobson Ring is one where the radical and Jacobson radical of an ideal agree, for all ideals.

(Assuming Ring = Unital & Commutative here)

We know the following about Artinian Rings:

- Quotients of an Artinian are Artinian.
- The Nilradical and Jacobson Radical of an Artinian Ring agree.

Putting these 2 together I believe we can deduce all Artinian Rings are Jacobson.

However, If this result is indeed true, I'm surprised it wasn't mentioned in lectures or find reference to it in any books.

If it doesn't hold, is there a counterexample?

Thanks

Henry

Comment: I meant to write ideal agree, i.e. for all ideals I, r(I) ,the radical of I equals the Jacobson radical of I

Comment: Oh ha, i see, then yes

Comment: I'm not aware of any standard notation for the Jacobson radical of an ideal

Comment: https://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Jacobson_ring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this notion I think you mean the well-known definition for commutative rings: every prime ideal is an intersection of maximal ideals.

It is equivalent to $J(R/I)=N(R/I)$ for all ideals $I\lhd R$.

Equivalently, that means the intersection of primes over $I$ (the "radical of $I$" and the intersection of maximal ideals over $I$ (the "Jacobson radical of $I$") coincide.

In an Artinian ring, a prime ideal is maximal, so each prime is trivially an intersection of a single maximal ideal.  That means that commutative Artinian rings are indeed Jacobson.

Comment: Yes, this is the right definition for the Jacobson radical. I'm asking if it makes the ring a Jacobson ring, as in https://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Jacobson_ring

Comment: @user1044791 And I said "yes" and gave a reason why. Did i leave something unclear?

Comment: @user1044791 [Here's one mention](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Encyclopaedia_of_Mathematics/GRLtCAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=artinian+%22jacobson+ring%22&pg=PA231&printsec=frontcover). But you're right, you'd think it'd be more often mentioned.

Comment: Actually it turns out you only need the DCC on chains of the form $xR\supseteq x^2R\supseteq x^3R\supseteq \ldots$ to get it to be Jacobson